# How to know before the compilation if a project will be build or not and make a custom task run or not

Tags: msbuild

I'm looking to create a msbuild custom task that will control how the assembly version is generated on a build.

The first problem that I'm facing is that I don't want to change the assembly version if the project has not changed.

Because changing the assembly version will make a change to the project, and because the project will be modified (by me), it will cause the project to be built. The project would not be built if my task did not run.

Is there a way in msbuild to get my task to run before compilation and to know if the project will actually be built or to know that the project has not changed.

Thanks

Comment: I researched the issue of knowing whether the project will be built or not some time ago. I looks impossible to know even whether it was built afterwards. But I still hope, someone knows.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to add version, your build system works and so on.

If you have one version for all assemblies in product you can create simple task with
condition whether svn/git/.. revision changed. And then add +1 to all AssemblyInfo.cs files.

The same solution you can apply on per project base.

Real conditions that is used to decide compile or not are too complex.

Comment: Indeed it is too complex to evaluate by myself if a project will be build or not. My question was about if msbuild offers an extension point or something to tell me "eh, the project X need to be build".